# Dicttoxml Module tags

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to make use of this module for some time now. I have many lists of dictionaries, that I want to convert into xml format. However, I want each list to essentially have its own 'table'. However When I try doing something along the lines of:

```
xml = dicttoxml.dictoxml(myList, root = False,
                         custom_root = "MyName",
                         attr_type = False)
```

I get every dict displayed as an `<item>` type. Shouldn't this produce what the module's owner refers to as an "xml snippet" that also is identified by the custom_root name?

Essentially I want each list to have its own identifier but not be created as 'root'. Basically where the following would have each item number associated to a certain list. Either encapsulating the whole list or each dict in the list would be suitable, I believe.

```
<root>
  <item1>
    #dict info
  </item1>
  <item2>
    #dict info
  </item2>
</root>
```

Comment: Could you include an example of what you want the XML to look like? Do you want all lists in one XML file or should each list be its own XML file?

Comment: I want all of the lists in one XML file, but I want each list to be separated by some sort of identifier. I'll edit my post in a minute.

Comment: Looking at the source of `dicttoxml` you can't easily pass a flag to that function to fix it. But you may be able to do each list separately and concatenate the result as desired.

Comment: I did run dicttoxml on each list separately. I called the 'xml' code on each of the lists. I tried concatenating them together in the file after I used only a custom root but each one has the declarations for an individual file.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by using just the `custom_root` variable in my call and leaving `root = True`. Then, I stripped the leading

`b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'`

by calling 
`xml.partition(b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>')[2]`

From then on, I created a file with `<root> </root>` tags and had the xml i created appended in between these tags.